# CalendarApp CreateEvent creates the event on the wrong calendar (calendar with different id)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to add a calendar event conditionally to 2 calendars for each row in my spreadsheet document.

```
function createCalendarEvent(calendarId, row) {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var lastName = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
   var firstName = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
   var title = lastName + ", " + firstName;
   var eventDate = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 12).getValue();
   var startTime = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange(row, 14).getValue());
   var endTime = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange(row, 15).getValue());
   var startDate = new Date(startTime.getTime());
   var endDate = new Date(endTime.getTime());
   startDate.setYear(eventDate.getYear());
   startDate.setMonth(eventDate.getMonth());
   startDate.setDate(eventDate.getDate());
   endDate.setYear(eventDate.getYear());
   endDate.setMonth(eventDate.getMonth());
   endDate.setDate(eventDate.getDate());
   var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
   Logger.log(calendar.getName());
   Logger.log(calendar.isOwnedByMe());
   Logger.log(calendar.getId());
   Logger.log(calendar.setSelected(true));
   var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(title, 
   startDate, endDate);
   Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```

the 2 calendar ids that I have and get passed to the function as argument look like :

```
"[my email username]@[my organization domain].com"
```

and

```
 "[somename].com_00t1jhqpsu15fcprbl98qg8erk@group.calendar.google.com"
```

when it executes it always adds the event to the first one.

any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the event in the default calendar:

```
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(title, startDate, endDate);
```

[You can find the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getdefaultcalendar)

Try changing it to:

```
var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startDate, endDate);
```

This way you'll use the calendar that you've found earlier (through the ID) in this row:

```
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
```